Found after a long time I had made mistakes in my Salah
After a long time of praying, I realized I had been reciting the tashahudd wrongly so much so that the meaning had changed slightly. Do I need to start redoing all of my improper Salah now that I know about the mistake. I know unintentional mistakes and forgiven by Allah and accepted but now that I realize my mistake do I make them up or not? Please give references to your answers.

Please can you edit in the wrong tashahudd you were praying so people can analyse the arabic to find the weight of the mistake.

In the hanafi school of thought, if you were unaware of such mistakes, you are not liable to repeat your previous prayers. However, as you are now aware of such, you must avoid these mistakes and you are liable for them, to the extent that making the mistake again would break your salaah.

This answer is according to Shia. Ignorant people are twofold, one is blamable and the other no, the guilty and the incapable. For example, if laziness prevents someone from going to learn the rules he needs to know in his/her life, then the mistaken prayers should be repeated. If the person has done all his efforts to learn what he needs, but yet again mistakes have appeared in his prayers, that would be forgiven and no repeating is required, although should be avoided from now on. [Here is a reference in Persian from Imam Khamenie]
